# How to change the order of the json parsing items in my listView?

Tags: php, android, json

I'm parsing data with JSON from my server database, but the presentation in my list is from the last id to the first. I would like to have the ids from 0 to whatever id I have, for example 20. Is that possible?

This is my php class:

```
<?
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$link1 = mysql_pconnect("host", "username", "pass") or die("Could not connect");
        mysql_select_db("dbname") or die("Could not select database");

$query= mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$rs = mysql_query("select * from vathmoi ORDER BY  vathmoi.id DESC");
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}
  function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
}
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', json_encode($arr));
echo '{"as_of":"Today!","trends":'.$str.'}';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ORDER BY  vathmoi.id DESC` to `ORDER BY  vathmoi.id ASC`

Also, look into using PHP's [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) function for outputting your JSON string.

Edit: Nevermind, I didn't see that you were using json_encode in that callback. Not sure why you need that callback... json_encode usually does a pretty good job of escaping your data so that it's valid JSON, but then again I do not know what data you're pulling from the DB.